# iPhone ASIHttpRequest - can't POST variables asynchronously

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, post, asihttprequest

Greetings,

I'm trying to simply POST data to a url using ASIHttpRequest.

Here is my code:

```
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostBody:[NSMutableData dataWithData:[@"uname=Hello" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *response=[request responseString];

    UIAlertView *msg=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Response" message:response delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [msg show];
    [msg release];
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error =[request error];
}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Basically, my url is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/login.php, when I dump the PHP $_POST variable, I just get an empty array - i.e. no POST parameters are sent! The rest of the PHP is tested and working fine.

I've looked through the allseeing-i.com documentation and examples and can't seem to resolve this problem.

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having the exact same problem.  I am using ASIHTTPRequest and trying to set my own POST data.  I have tried both [request setPostBody:] and [request appendPostData:].

When I run these lines just before I start the request, I find that both the method and the data are what I expect.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [request requestMethod]);
NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[[request postBody] bytes]
                                      length:[[request postBody] length]
                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]);
```

When I send it to the server, however, the request is made and logged but the POST data is empty.

I have, however, gotten my code working by switching to ASIFormDataRequest.

Reading the [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#put_requests_and_custom_posts), however, suggests to me that what you and I are doing should be working, so I suspect that is a bug in ASIHTTPRequest and I will contact the author to see if this is the case.

**Update**

One possibility is that the code is redirecting to another URL.  In that case, the post data may be dropped.  If that is the case, you can try using

```
[request setShouldUseRFC2616RedirectBehaviour:YES];⠀⠀⠀
```

which will allow the request to send the post data to the redirected URL.

Comment: Use ASIFormDataRequest! not ASIHttpRequest, then you can add POST variables using setPostValue()

Comment: Yes, as I said in my message, I had gotten the code working with ASIFormDataRequest.  That wasn't really the point, which was that the code wasn't working as it documentation says it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to setup the callback functions for async.

```
-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
   NSLog([request responseString]);
}
```

edit: looking again, u had some completion block code there... never seen that before, but maybe that takes care of what i posted above

Comment: Hey, I got it to work now: use __block ASIFormDataRequest *request=[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc ]initWithURL:url]; instead of ASIHttpRequest. That way you can add parameters using setPostValue...